# I am confused about JavaScript functions?

Tags: javascript, function

Does JavaScript functions attached to any particular object they are defined in or to global object itself, I ask this question because you can use function almost on any objects weather that function is part of that object or not, I mean you can assign function reference to any object you want so this mean that functions are by itself stored some where else and then we assign them to any other objects method.

Please correct me I am new to JavaScript but I know JavaScript to some extend.

I know the use of this keyword which is used to reference to the current context code.

Comment: and i know that function depends on how its called

Comment: Please post questions with better titles when posting to Stack Overflow.

Comment: We can't give an answer to this because we can't see any code that you're referencing. Please provide code.

Comment: pls read my question its all written there i thought there is no need to write code because i am explaining everything .

Comment: i just want a general answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions aren't attached to anything, but when executing they do so in a context where `this` is bound to some object (except for ES5 strict mode, where `this` can sometimes be undefined).

Which object `this` refers to is a product of how the function is invoked, if it is as a member of an object, or whether a function such as `call` or `apply` is used.

```
var obj = {
  x: 20,
  fn: function() {
    console.log(this.x);
  }
};
obj.fn(); // prints 20 as `this` will now point to the object `obj`

var x = 10;
var fn = obj.fn;
fn(); // prints 10 as `this` will now point to the global context, since we're invoking the function directly

var newObj = {
  x: 30
};
fn.call(newObj); // prints 30 as `this` points to newObj
fn.apply(newObj); // same as the above, but takes an the functions arguments as an array instead of individual arguments
```

Comment: thank u very much kinsey you saved my soul .